# Overwriting Feature Service with additional Layer in AGOL

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, feature-service

I have a feature service published, new data daily which is in the form of an additional layer. I use the feature service in a webmap, but after the service is overwritten the additional layer is not added, I just delete the layer and re-add.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am a tad confused at what you mean (probably just me!).  You published a service from an MXD.  Later you went back and added a new layer to that same MXD and then when you republished the service the new layer is not appearing in the service or when you add the service to your web map?

Comment: correct, i overwrote the existing service with an added layer. Looking for a way for it to appear automatically in my webmap vs having to remove the old layers one by one and re-add

Comment: When you add it to your Web Map are you adding the feature services individually or the Map Service.  I could be mistaken but I thought if you load the Map Service (and not load each feature service by its index) Any changes to the Map Service will automatically appear in the web map.  I will have a chance in about an hour I can test that.

Comment: one feature service, containing multiple layers

Comment: If you are adding a new layer to the service it wont show up in the web map b/c it wont be in the JSON of the web map. The web map will be referencing the layers that have been added to the map.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks! No way to have it happen automatically?